# C++ Single instance application with interrupt of main instance

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing an application using Qt5.7.1 which suppose to run as single instance application.

One of the requirements is whenever user launches second instance of application, this instance should notify original one and exit.

To achieve that I wrote a class below (based off the SO question on similar topic).

**However I am unhappy with warning `QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication` and the fact that it may trigger `interruptedCallback()` multiple times. Any improvement suggestions?**

runguard.h

```
#ifndef RUNGUARD_H
#define RUNGUARD_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSystemSemaphore>
#include <QThread>

class RunGuardChecker: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    RunGuardChecker(QSystemSemaphore *sem);
    ~RunGuardChecker();
    bool couldAcquireLock = false;
    bool check();
private:
    QSystemSemaphore *memLock;
    QThread checkThread;
    bool closeThread = false;
public slots:
    void checkFunc();
signals:
    void doneChecking();
};

class RunGuard: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    RunGuard(const char *key);
    ~RunGuard();

    bool isAnotherRunning();
    void lock();

private:
    QSystemSemaphore memLock;

    QThread lockThread;
    bool shouldTerminateLock = false;

    RunGuardChecker checker;

private slots:
    void lockLoop();

signals:
    void interrupted();
};

#endif // RUNGUARD_H
```

runguard.cpp

```
#include "RunGuard.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

RunGuard::RunGuard(const char *key)
    : QObject(NULL)
    , memLock(key, 0, QSystemSemaphore::Create)
    , checker(&memLock)
{
    memLock.release(1);
}

RunGuard::~RunGuard()
{
    shouldTerminateLock = true;
    lockThread.terminate();
    while (lockThread.wait(100) == false) {
        memLock.release();
    }
}

bool RunGuard::isAnotherRunning()
{
    return checker.check();
}

void RunGuard::lock()
{
    // Ensure flag is set correctly
    shouldTerminateLock = false;

    // Start lock thread
    moveToThread(&lockThread);
    connect(&lockThread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(lockLoop()));
    lockThread.start();
}

void RunGuard::lockLoop()
{
    while(shouldTerminateLock == false) {
        memLock.acquire();
        if (shouldTerminateLock == false) {
            emit interrupted();
        }
    }
}

RunGuardChecker::RunGuardChecker(QSystemSemaphore *sem)
    : QObject(NULL)
{
    this->memLock = sem;
}

bool RunGuardChecker::check()
{
    bool result = true;
    // Start check function in another thread
    moveToThread(&checkThread);
    connect(&checkThread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(checkFunc()));
    checkThread.start();
    // Wait 100 milliseconds
    QThread::msleep(100);
    // Check if we acquired the lock
    // If we acquired, we should release,
    // if we did not acquire:
    // then we should send interrupt (release [1]),
    // release [2] (so that we acquire)
    // and then release again.
    memLock->release();
    if (this->couldAcquireLock == true) {
        result = false;
    }

    // Close thread safely
    checkThread.terminate();
    while (checkThread.wait(100) == false) {
        memLock->release();
    }
    return result;
}

void RunGuardChecker::checkFunc()
{
    bool result = memLock->acquire();
    if (result) {
        this->couldAcquireLock = result;
    }
    return;
}

RunGuardChecker::~RunGuardChecker()
{

}
```

Use like follows:

main.cpp

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "application.h"
#include "runguard.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    RunGuard guard("app");
    if (guard.isAnotherRunning() == true) {
        return 0;
    }
    guard.lock();

    // Application class implements custom slot "interruptedCallback()"
    Application app(argc, argv);
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);

    QMainWindow window;
    window.show();

    app.window = &window;

    app.connect(&guard, SIGNAL(interrupted()), &app, SLOT(interruptedCallback()));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: It's funny how I run into the same issue and Google suggests me _this_ solution